# Can't use load function in julia simple script

Tags: julia, google-colaboratory, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to load a image in Julia but it gives me the error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: `load` not defined
> Stacktrace:
> [1](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb) top-level scope
> @ c:\folde1\folder2\project.jl

My code is:

```
using TestImages, Images, Statistics, Plots
a = load("rachado1.jpeg")
```

I'm running the code using vscode with Julia v1.9
I already tried installing many packages (FileIO, ImageIO, ImageMagick), but the error persists.

I also tried in colab following [these instructions (Julia in colab)](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb) and adding a new cell using the script above. But I got the same error.

Comment: For `load` you would need `FileIO` and `ImageIO`, but not just installed, but imported. Try doing `using ImageIO` before the `load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Dan Getz said, the issue is not importing FileIO:

```
# Try to load the image
img = load("test.jpg") # ERROR: UndefVarError: load not defined


using FileIO # now instead import FileIO first

img = load("test.jpg") # it now loads successfully
```

hope this helps!